# Only keep rows per each value in one column BEFORE (time-based) a certain condition is fulfilled in another column

Tags: sql, grouping, presto, partition

I have a table of orders, numerated by `order_id`. Other relevant columns include `customer_id`, `timestamp`, and `Condition_column`. For each `customer_id`, I want to only keep the rows BEFORE (aka `timestamp<=` ) the first time their `Condition_column` is not `null`.

My dataserver is presto, and I believe this should be possible with some `OVER PARTITION BY` statements; but I can't figure out how.

Here's an example table:

```
order_id    customer_id    timestamp    Condition_col
abc          stan           5/11/19
def          stan           5/20/19
efg          stan           6/1/19       text
hij          stan           6/9/19       text2
jkl          jimmy          5/22/19      text3
klm          mike           5/01/19      
lmn          mike           5/17/19      
xyz          mike           5/30/19      text4
wyt          sam            5/4/19       text5
ard          sam            5/24/19      text6
shd          sam            6/5/19       text7
```

Here's what I want as result:

```
order_id    customer_id    timestamp    Condition_col
abc          stan           5/11/19
def          stan           5/20/19
efg          stan           6/1/19       text
jkl          jimmy          5/22/19      text3
klm          mike           5/01/19      
lmn          mike           5/17/19      
xyz          mike           5/30/19      text4
wyt          sam            5/4/19       text5
```

I'm kinda stuck in trying to figure out how to logically write this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when condition_col is not null then timestamp end) over (partition by customer_id) as min_condition_ts
      from t
     ) t
where min_condition_ts is null or  -- no non-NULL value
      timestamp <= min_condition_ts;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!!